# Can't debug correctly in Eclipse C++ using MinGW32

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, mingw

I am trying to use `gdb` to debug my C++ application in `Eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)`. The problem is that I get the following in the stack trace although the debugger should stop at the beginning of main:

```
<terminated, exit value: 0>gdb (7.6.1)
```

If I use any variables in the source code, they don't show up in `Variables` tab.

The code I am testing the debugger with is the typical "hello world" program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

I have Mingw32 g++ installed and I can compile with no problems. I tried running gdb in the command prompt and it shows that it is installed: `GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 8.1.1-1) 8.1.1`.

I have the environment variable: `MINGW_HOME` pointing to the parent directory containing `bin` and other directories.

In the `Debug Configurations` -> `Debugger` , I have the value `GDB debugger` set to `gdb` and `GDB command file` set to `.gdbinit`

What could possibly be the problem? My system has `Cygwin`, `mingw32` and `mingw64` installed earlier and I think the debugger might be using `Cygwin` instead of `mingw32`. Is this the problem? How can I make sure that all my building and debugging is made through only `mingW32`?

Used tools:
`GCC Assembler
GCC Archiver
GCC C++ Compiler
GCC C Compiler
MinGW C Linker
MinGW C++ Linker`

**EDIT:**
I removed Cygwin and changed its environment path to point at `C:\MinGW\bin`. Now if I check for `gdb` the following prints:
`GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1` instead of the Cygwin: `GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 8.1.1-1) 8.1.1`. I tried launching the debugger again but still the same issue.

Comment: did you enable debug symbols when you compiled (`-g`)?

Comment: I am using maximum `-g3`